# Suppress mkdir warning while still executing the OR option?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mkdir

I have a bash script that sets a directory as a lock, and if the lock is in place then it send a message to the user who attempted to run it.

I'm wondering if its possible to somehow suppress the "directory already exists" message, but still run the other function (warning_run_in_place). Because if using the -p flag on mkdir it would not execute the warning_run_in_place portion.

Essentially it's something like

```
mkdir MYLOCK || warning_run_in_place

warning_run_in_place() 
{
  echo "Hey I'm already running..."
  exit 1;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. `mkdir MYLOCK || warning_run_in_place >/dev/null` would discard the warning message (though properly speaking you should be printing diagnostics to standard error; `echo "warning" >&2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

`mkdir MYLOCK`

by:

`mkdir MYLOCK 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `-p` option in `mkdir` command (as documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir)):

```
  mkdir -p MYLOCK || warning_run_in_place
```

Comment: That's specifically what the OP is not asking about; `mkdir -p` will not fail if the directory exists.